# Dynamic image add on another image for jewelry site

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I need help making a jewelry shopping site in ASP.NET for dynamic image-adding.

When a customer visits the site, he/she could take his/her own photo from a webcam and the photo will be saved into the database until the time the customer is available in that site.  When the customer selects the jeweler items by clicking on them, the item will be visible on a customer image (necklaces, earring, ect).  It would be visible on the customer's neck and ears.  With that image, the customer could decide whichever is suitable.  Then he/she could shop for items comfortably.

Please help me with the dynamic image (clicking) on the customer image.  This is for ASP.NET and C#.

Answer (score 0):

Big stuff

You will have to implement face detection and stick the jewellery items on the pic of user.

Near to impossible. This requires a very powerfull image processing library.

Better you take a fixed pic on your site for which you know the coordinates or nose,neck,ears etc and then you can easily merge the selected items pic onto it.

Comment: suppose i have one image which is saved in the database.only one photo of customer. and other 3 image of neckles,ear ring and nose ring.i will click on the neckles and the neckles will move to customer neck.Is it possible through jquery ?only 3 image.dynamic

Comment: no javascript does not have that much power for image processing. You will have to use some image processing libraries. google for Aforge and OpenCV

Comment: using jquery it could be possible only if the neck,nose & ears are known to be where(x,y coordinates) in the customer's image

its better you take a fixed photo of statue and do your stuff